# Is there way run uvm_sequences on ovm_agent?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

We are in process to migrate our TB to UVM.
I am working on first IP that will be verified using UVM.
I have to find out if it is possible to reuse my uvm_sequences in SOC that remains in OVM mean time.
In case it is possible , like find example how it's done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot mix OVM and UVM that way. You should be able to write your uvm_sequence in such a way that it work in both by simply changing your **u**'s to **o**'s. You would have to limit your sequence to functionality that exists in both.

If you use UVM RAL. there is [a package](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/downloads/uvm-register-kit-ovm-2.1.2) that integrates that functionality back into OVM.

There is another package, [ovm_container](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/downloads/ovmcontainer-virtual-interfaces-and-configuration), that gives you the functionality of uvm_config_db.